# PHP Class Name Unable to Identify "FN" Name After Update

Tags: php

PHP Version 7.4.6
Unable to Identify "**FN**" Name After Update.
It gives the following error

```
$_FN = new FN();
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'FN' (T_FN), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in D:\System\Xampp\htdocs\Engine\ClsFunction.php on line 4

```
   class FN {
     function DPS(){
      return "TEST";
     } 
    }

   $_FN = new FN();
   Echo $_FN->DPS();
```

Answer (score 3):

This is about how one can write arrow function in PHP 7.4

previously, one should write anonymous function like this :

```
$foo = some_function_needing_a_callback(function($bar)
{
    return $bar->Something;
}, $bars);
```

As of PHP 7.4, this can be onlined this way :

```
$foo = some_function_needing_a_callback(fn($bar) => $bar->Something, $bars);
```

As you can notice, the arrow function is used calling the function [`fn()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php). This makes the `FN` name invalid for a class

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading my PHP server to 7.4.13 I found that I also started getting the exception "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Fn' (T_FN), expecting identifier (T_STRING)...", however I am using Fn in a namespace context.

I believe "Fn" is now a reserved keyword as the error went away after I changed my namespace to "Fnc".

I was searching for several days for an answer thinking  the problem was with an initial backspace before the namespace before I stumbled on this post and realised the issue was with the actual "Fn" namespace name itself.